# In WordPress how do you create a custom post type with the author's name in the slug?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I'm trying to build a new WordPress theme using register_post_type to create a custom post type called listings.

I would like each listing to have the following permalink structure:

http://www.mysite.com/%author%/listing-title

I'm not quite sure how to achieve this with the CPT controls listed in the Codex. Previously, I have a achieved a similar effect by creating a custom structure in Permalink Settings:

```
/%author%/%postname%/
```

It has been [suggested on the main forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980737/in-wordpress-how-do-you-create-a-custom-post-type-with-the-authors-name-in-the-s) that I use wp_rewrite, but wp_rewrite only seems to deal with incoming requests and does not change the way CPT posts are created.

To illustrate further with an image, I want to change the /listings/ part of the permalink URL to the post author's name. See image below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My plugin [Custom Post Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-permalinks/) allows you to set permalink structures for custom post types and it supports post authors as part of a permastruct. However, while my plugin will enable you to set up that structure, I don't suggest using that structure. That structure will essentially make WordPress interpret all top-level pages as 404 errors (and second level pages, I think). You should be fine if you add the post type to anchor the beginning of the structure like this:

```
/%post_type%/%author%/%postname%/
```

Comment: Cool plugin, works great!

Comment: I followed your advice and accepted the need to maintain the initial /%post_type%/ section. But am now thinking it would be nice to add a /blog/ section to my non-custom post types for consistency.